# ACCESS SQL query: adding a new field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to add a field to a existing query that doesn't get affected from 'Where function'

For example,

This is the original code....

```
SELECT SHELL_Payables.PoolNum, 
A.[Code], B.[Program] AS Program, A.PayableAmt, C.ReceivableAmt  INTO [New Data]

FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID 
              INNER JOIN C  ON A.Num=B.Num

WHERE (((A.AccountingPeriod)<=[AccountingYearMonth]));
```

---

I would like to add A.PayableAmt again but this time where clause `(accountingperiod <= accountingyearMonth)` should not be applied to this field...

Any ideas? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: include sample data, with expected output

Comment: @PeterJeong Do you need the `PayableAmt` field to be displayed twice in the same row or is it a separate row where the filter is not applied?

Comment: @FutbolFan For the output, it should be displayed twice in the same row, but named differently

Comment: If you provide some sample data and expected output. it would be easier to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `union` and `select into`, you would need to write your query something like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO [New Data]
FROM (
    SELECT PoolNum
        ,A.[Code]
        ,B.[Program] AS Program
        ,A.PayableAmt
        ,C.ReceivableAmt
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
    INNER JOIN C ON A.Num = B.Num
    WHERE A.AccountingPeriod <= AccountingYearMonth

    UNION 

    SELECT PoolNum
        ,A.[Code]
        ,B.[Program] AS Program
        ,A.PayableAmt
        ,C.ReceivableAmt
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
    INNER JOIN C ON A.Num = B.Num
    )
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to add another `PayableAmt` column to the same row, maybe you can join back to the table A something like this:

```
SELECT   t.PoolNum
        ,a.[Code]
        ,a.[Program] AS Program
        ,t.PayableAmt
        ,a.PayableAmt AS NewPayableAmt
        ,C.ReceivableAmt
INTO [New Data]
FROM A
LEFT JOIN 
 (
    SELECT 
         PoolNum
        ,A.[Code]
        ,B.[Program] AS Program
        ,A.PayableAmt
        ,C.ReceivableAmt
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
    INNER JOIN C ON A.Num = B.Num
    WHERE A.AccountingPeriod <= AccountingYearMonth
   ) t
   ON t.Code = A.Code --assuming this is unique
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON A.Num = B.Num
```

Comment: i really like this version..but "ON t.Code = A.Code" this is not unique.. There are no unique field here... Sorry

Comment: Try adding distinct in your outer select.

Comment: I got it !! u saved my life!! Thanks.

Comment: Quick question... I somehow got the exact same value for t.PayableAmt
        and a.PayableAmt AS NewPayableAmt... any ideas?

Comment: Hmm...It should be the same value if the following condition is not true, otherwise should return different values. `A.AccountingPeriod)<=[AccountingYearMonth]`